# React 'Invariant Violation' in rendering a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I'm getting the following error when trying to add an `onClick` property to a `<td>` element inside of a table. Here is my error:

> Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(...) ...
>   Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like ... or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID.

I've read a few variants of the same problem, but most of the problems result from using improper table structure. My table is structured properly. Here is my full function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Field</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {Object.keys(user).map(function(key) {
                    let val = user[key];
                    if (typeof val === 'string') {
                        return (
                            <tr key={user[key]}>
                                <th>{key}</th>
                                <td onClick={this.handleClick}>{val}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    }
                }, this)}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

The error *only* exists when I set the `onClick` property, it runs without error when it's removed.

What's the cause of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Everything seems legit to me. I would've tried to declare variable with var instead of let.

Comment: Can reactjs even do nested return statements?

Comment: Why do you add `onClick` handler to all `td` elements? That may seriously affect performance if the amount of `td`-s is big. You may use [event delegation pattern](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) and add only one handler to `table` of `tbody`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `user[key]` was declared as a property of my `<tr>`. One of the resulting values was a fairly lengthy string that React wouldn't accept as a valid key. Changing `<tr key={i}>` fixed the problem. I'm not sure why I was setting the key as anything else to begin with, but thought I'd share in case anyone else is getting a similar error.